# Missing signatures for debian repo

Tags: debian, apt

I've recently upgraded my system to Debian 12, and I'm noticing these errors when I try to run

```
sudo apt update
```

This is my output:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Err:1 http://security.debian.org bookworm-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease                                                      
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                                                              
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Reading package lists... Done
```

Also, my current sources.list file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware 

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware 

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmwares 

deb http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

At first I had a couple more missing signature errors, for nodejs and for vscode repos.
So I've reinstalled these apps and it seems they've added a `.gpg` file to `/etc/apt/keyrings` and I've noticed that their corresponding entry under /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ was updated with `signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/...`. After this these 2 extra `NO_PUBKEY` errors were gone, which makes absolute sense.

I have some of an undertanding of why this is more secure, but what I'm missing is where do I get these keys when it comes to the debian repos.

Am I missing something, or did I probably mess something when upgrading to Debian 12 from 11?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you do the upgrade?

Comment: there should be a whole bunch of keys in `/usr/share/keyrings` - they'd be installed by `debian-keyring` and `debian-archive-keyring` packages

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I've followed the docs here https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade

Comment: @JaromandaX, yep I see 3 .gpg files for bookworm there. Should I follow the same logic as in sources.list.d? I.e. adding the signed-by= key?

Comment: no, that's not what I was suggesting

Comment: @JaromandaX, what are you suggesting then?

Comment: suggesting nothing, checking to see what may be missing from your install

Comment: @JaromandaX: I do not argue against better security, but there is no simple way to disable it for a while, for various reason.   @jalxp: In some conditions I can override some security errors with: `deb [trusted=yes] http: ...` in `sources.list`, `APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true";` and `Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "true";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/11trust` . @All: The packaging system is one of the best Debian feature, but the security innovation even necessary are not well documented, especially for begginers.